# Flutter gen-l10n localization. Can't import 'package:flutter_gen/l10n/app_localizations.dart';

Tags: flutter, localization

I am writing flutter application with localization support.

It worked locally, I generated code using flutter gen-l10n and was able to use
`import 'package:flutter_gen/l10n/app_localizations.dart';` .

Then I decided to automate code compilation using github actions, but wasn't able as I got
`Building Linux application...                                    ERROR: lib/main.dart:3:8: Error: Error when reading '.dart_tool/flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart': No such file or directory ERROR: import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart'; ERROR:        ^ ERROR: lib/src/views/home_page.dart:2:8: Error: Error when reading '.dart_tool/flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart': No such file or directory`

How can I fix this?

I decided to move output files to lib directory and ran a command
`flutter gen-l10n --output-dir=./lib/flutter_gen`,
but anyway code was generated inside .dart_tool directory, so every time I use `flutter gen-l10n`   I copy generated directory to lib

Answer (score 0):

When you use `flutter gen-l10n`, they are by default placed in the `.dart_tool` directory, potentially causing issues in specific environments like GitHub Actions workflow.

Make sure that you have the correct configuration in your `pubspec.yaml`

```
flutter:
  generate:
    - gen_l10n
```

move generated localization files to your lib directory

```
lib/
  flutter_gen/
    l10n/
      ...
```

Do other necessary processes like importing `app_localizations` package. now you won't need to manually copy the generated directory each time you run `flutter gen-l10n`.